# Python: __cmp__ and testing list membership

Tags: python, comparison

Apologies if someone has already addressed this, but I couldn't find an answer.

I have a problem where I overrode `__cmp__` for a custom class, similar to this:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, prop):
        self.prop = prop
    def __cmp__(self, other):
        return cmp(self.prop, other.prop)

a = MyClass(1)
b = MyClass(2)
c = MyClass(3)
d = MyClass(1)

my_list = [a, b, c]
print a in my_list
print b in my_list
print c in my_list
print d in my_list

# Output:
#
# True
# True
# True
# True
```

Reading the docs tells me that this is expected, because:

> For the list and tuple types, x in y is true if and only if there exists an index i such that x == y[i] is true.

My question is two-fold:

- Why does Python (2.7) use `==` rather than `is` to test list membership?
- Is there a better way to be doing this, such that I can test whether a specific instance of my class is actually in a container *and* be able to compare instances based on their attributes?

Comment: The list contains a value equal to the variable, not a reference to the variable.

Comment: Actually, I added `print a is my_list[0]; print d is my_list[0]` and got `True` and `False` respectively. Doesn't this suggest that it does contain the instance itself?

Comment: Yes, see my answer for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - Why does Python (2.7) use `==` rather than `is` to test list membership?

Because equality is usually more interesting than identity for containment checking, especially when two different objects can have the same value.

```
>>> ('Hello, ' + 'world!') is 'Hello, world!'
False
>>> ('Hello, ' + 'world!') == 'Hello, world!'
True
```

> - Is there a better way to be doing this, such that I can test whether a specific instance of my class is actually in a container and be able to compare instances based on their attributes?

Not especially.

Answer (score 0):

The list contains a value equal to the variable, not a reference to the variable. Think about it this way. Are these two code samples the same? What makes them different?

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.name == other.name

# sample one

sam = Person('Sam')
bob = Person('Bob')

people = [sam, bob]
```

The first sample is when you should use the is keyword. You're trying to test if the object in the list is the object outside of the list, meaning the sam inside the list is stored in the same place in memory as the sam outside the list.

```
# sample two

sam = Person('Sam')
bob = Person('Bob')

people = [Person('Sam'), Person('Bob')]
```

This sample is when you should use the double equals keyword. You're trying to test if the object in the list has the value when compared to the object outside of the list. Notice, that because we instantiated to different people with the name Sam, they will be equal in value but not the same object.